# How can I call contract's function from the Jaxx wallet?

Tags: contract-development, wallets, light-clients, jaxx

[As I know](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3241/is-there-any-ethereum-online-light-client-wallet-that-can-accept-smart-contracts), at this date there is no Ethereum's light wallets, which supports contracts. But in Jaxx wallet, it's possible to send some `Custom Data` to the contract.

[image]

So, the question is: if I have a simple contact like `greeter` ([source](https://www.ethereum.org/greeter)), how can I call `greet` function from the Jaxx?

Comment: Currently trying to find out if you may use Jaxx wallet to sign transactions in the browser. Any Jaxx dev there to help us out?

Answer (score 2):

You should try [Metamask](http://metamask.io).
It's a browser extension injecting web3js into the browser. You can use it to interact with your apps smart contracts.